# How to parse message for a log4j2 JDBC Appender

Tags: java, log4j2

In my application, I use a pre determined log messages, something like this:

`MESSAGE_ID     PROCESS_ID   This process is running`

I would like to use a JDBC Appender and split my message in three, to get put each part in a particular SQL column.

Is this possible? And How?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you show me an output message?

Comment: LAU0005I    [0a2b0fa5-4809-4888-b81f-8ca3704aebc5]     Type de flux récupéré ExempleStream

Comment: I am not quite sure which part of message is what. LAU0005I seems to be MESSAGE_ID, the string in [ ] seems to be process ID. The last part means "this process is running." Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You're absolutely right

Comment: Can you access the message generated by log in your program already?

Comment: Yes, I can access it

Comment: Could you show me the part of your code which generates the message and the part which can access it?

Comment: Right now, the message is in a property file, like this: `LAU000051 = LAU00005I\t[%s]\tThis process is running`  and then, I do something like that `log.info(messages.getString("LAU00005I"), this.id);`

Comment: Why can you not simply add the variables separately into the DB without having to split the generated string?

Comment: I can, I simply do not know how to do that with a jdbc appender for log4j2

Comment: I've no idea how to do that. But since you only need to put different parts of a string into a DB(i maybe wrong), you can simply do it with a normal JDBC connection.

Comment: That is what I do now, but using the JDBCAppender seems to be a more elegant solution

Comment: Well good luck with it, google on how to use JDBCAppender. Youtube is a good thing to search on too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to use the [ThreadContext](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html) to carry the message ID and process ID, and [declare jdbc columns](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender) for each item like this:

```
<Column name="MESSAGE" pattern="%message" />
<Column name="MESSAGE_ID" pattern="%X{messageID}" />
<Column name="PROCESS_ID" pattern="%X{processID}" />
```

In your code you set the values like this:

```
ThreadContext.put("messageID", UUID.randomUUID().toString();
ThreadContext.put("processID", getProcessId());
...
logger.debug("this process is running");
...
```

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!